# Is it possible for a SP to do this in SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server, oracle, stored-procedures

I have to migrate from SQL Server to Oracle and i have this SP

```
ALTER procedure ST_004_264_01_14292
  @n1 decimal(4,2),
  @n2 decimal(4,2),
  @resultado decimal(4,2) output
  as 
   select @resultado=(@n1+@n2)/2;


 drop procedure ST_004_264_01_14292

  declare @variable decimal(4,2)
  execute ST_004_264_01_14292 5,6, @variable output
  select @variable;
```

Comment: Looks more like a Scalar Function to me.

Comment: Presumably that `drop` is not actually part of the SP?

Comment: The drop is inside the SP. I need to rewrite it in PL/SQL but i have no idea what to do.

Comment: by *do this* do you mean to drop itself?

Comment: I suppose that a SP dropping itself is neither possible in SQL Server nor in Oracle

Comment: Yes. I dont understand why this SP is droping itself, but i have to create it in Oracle. I dont know if it`s gonna compile.

Comment: Well, as you can see from my answer, it is possible in SQL Server. I don't have an oracle database to test on, nor do I have enough experience with oracle to know if it's possible on oracle.

Comment: What's even more mind-boggling is that the drop is followed shortly thereafter by an execute of the same stored procedure.

Comment: You can create a procedure in Oracle that will attempt to drop itself using an `EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'drop procedure procedure_name';` statement, but when the procedure get's to that command it will block.  Oracle won't drop an object that is currently in use until all transactions using that object either commit or rollback.  You end up with a deadlock and the procedure just hangs.

Comment: Perhaps if you describe your goals their may be an alternative solution that doesn't involve recursive self annihilating procedures.

Comment: Thanks for the answers! I have to migrate 3 SQL Server DBs to Oracle for a client, i dont know when or how they are gonna use it, and i dont have any type of documentation. It`s a really shitty project.

Comment: If you have that stored procedure, then it's never been executed before, otherwise it would be gone.  Don't bother converting it.

Answer (score 3):

Assuming I understand your question, then the answer is yes. 
It is possible for a procedure to drop itself. (though I can't understand why would anyone want to do such a thing)

Tested on sql server 2012:

```
create procedure stp_test
    (
        @CountBefore int output,
        @CountAfter int output
    )
AS
begin
    select @CountBefore = count(*)
    from sys.procedures 
    where name = 'stp_test'

    drop procedure stp_test

    select @CountAfter = count(*)
    from sys.procedures 
    where name = 'stp_test'
end
GO

declare @x int,
        @y int

exec stp_test @x  output, @y output

select @x as [count before], @y as [count after]
```

Results:

```
count before count after
------------ -----------
1            0
```